# How do I reference a model column via string?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm making a terminal command where the user enters two strings. One will correspond to a model and the other to a column from that model.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--model",
            dest="model",
            required=True,
        )
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--col",
            dest="col",
            required=True,
        )
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    # Handle stuff here
```

I know I can do `from django.apps import apps` and put `options["model"]` in `apps.get_model()` to get an instance of the model the user inputs, assuming  it exists. But How can I reference the column the user inputs in `options["col"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should remove the duplicate `add_argument` method. And secondly, you should require the name of the `app` because what will happen if two different apps share the same model name? And what if these same-named models share same field names. On which column should this command apply?

Here is a working command (that accepts an `app` argument, as well):

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.core.exceptions import FieldDoesNotExist
from django.apps import apps


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--app",
            dest="app",
            required=True,
        )

        parser.add_argument(
            "--model",
            dest="model",
            required=True,
        )

        parser.add_argument(
            "--col",
            dest="col",
            required=True,
        )

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        app_label = options.get('app')
        model_name = options.get('model')
        column_name = options.get('col')

        try:
            model = apps.get_model(app_label=app_label, model_name=model_name)
        except LookupError as e:
            msg = 'The model "%s" under the app "%s" does not exist!' \
                  % (model_name, app_label)
            raise CommandError(msg)
        try:
            column = model._meta.get_field(column_name)
        except FieldDoesNotExist as e:
            msg = 'The column "%s" does not match!' % column_name
            raise CommandError(msg)
        else:
            print(column, type(column))
            # Do stuff here with the column, model.
```